# get user's LinkedIn experiences using Auth0 - missing permission r_basicprofile

Tags: linkedin-api, auth0

I am using Auth0 to sign up my users to my SaaS.

I am trying to get access to user's experiences using LinkedIn SSO,

The sign up with LinkedIn works like a charm, but the problem is, when I click the "Basic Profile" option, I ends up with

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Scope 'r_basicprofile' is not authorized for your application"
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it needs LinkedIn approval. Therefore, I tried to add `r_basicprofile` in my LinkedIn Developers account, I added the product "Sign In with LinkedIn", "Share on LinkedIn" but it did not added me the magical `r_basicprofile` authorization.

Am I the only one trying to do that?
Any helps -- or links to LinkedIn's up-to-date documentation would be helpful!

Edit: I saw that `r_basicprofile` is part of the API v1 and to access you apparently [have to apply to LinkedIn Marketing API Program for the permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext#what-permissions-do-i-have-access-to). I hope that is true...

> What permissions do I have access to? LinkedIn v1 APIs provided the
> following set of permissions:
>
> r_basicprofile r_emailaddress w_share rw_company_admin Moving forward,
> the available v2 APIs include:
>
> r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile) r_emailaddress w_member_social
> (replaces w_share) Looking to maintain access to rw_company_admin?
> Apply to the LinkedIn Marketing API Program to continue managing your
> Company Pages.

Comment: You need a ["LinkedIn Partner Program"](https://developer.linkedin.com/content/developer/global/en_us/index/partner-programs/apply) application for that. Normal applications only have access to `r_liteprofile` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile

Comment: @brc-dd do you think the integration out-of-the-box from Auth0 will work after I apply?

Comment: Most probably no. The login part will work. To get the complete profile, you'll need to manually call LinkedIn's API with the access token obtained from Auth0's management API (https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/calling-an-external-idp-api)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's an issue with Auth0 that hasn't yet updated the scope to be used. LinkedIn changed the scope '**r_liteprofile**' to '**profile**'.

Currently, the scopes have these names:

[image]

But previously, they had these names:

[image]

The app generates the following URL:

> ...linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?login_hint=&prompt=login&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%xxxx.eu.auth0.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback&scope=**r_liteprofile**&state=xxxx&client_id=xxxxx

Which should actually be:

> linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?login_hint=&prompt=login&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%xxxx.eu.auth0.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback&scope=**profile**&state=xxxx&client_id=xxxxx

This is my theory, but at least it makes sense to me.

I hope someone from the Auth0 team could review this issue.

ref : https://community.auth0.com/t/the-linkedin-login-is-deprecated-updating-to-the-new-scopes-is-necessary/113696